# Issue with Codable object to JSON conversion

Tags: json, swift, mongodb

Apologies if this is a basic question, I am new using Apis and JSON in Swift. I am attempting to submit a post request but am receiving:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'`.

I believe that this is due to a incorrect/unconvertible type but I have tried multiple different permutations of the variables I am passing and it continues to fail.

Here is my `ContentView`:

```java
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var town: Space = Space(title: "test city", description: "is this working")
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            Api.postRequest(param: ["space" : town], urlString: Api.spacePostUrl) { (update) in
                print("\(update)")
            }
        }) {
            Text("Post Request")
        }
    }
}
```

The underlying data `struct`:

```java
struct Space: Codable {
    var title: String
    var description: String
}
```

And my attempted API call:

```java
class Api {
    static let spacePostUrl = "http://localhost:3001/spaces"
    static let spaceGetUrl = "http://localhost:3001/"
    
    static func postRequest(param: [String : Codable], urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpBody = body
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, request, error) in
            guard let update = data else { return }
            do {
                let update = try JSONDecoder().decode(Int.self, from: update)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(update)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Api {
     static let spacePostUrl = "http://localhost:3001/spaces"
     static let spaceGetUrl = "http://localhost:3001/"

     static func postRequest(param: [String : Codable], urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    
    let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpBody = body
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, request, error) in
        guard let update = data else { return }
        do {
            let update = try JSONDecoder().decode(Space.self, from: update)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(update)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
   task.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still throws the same error, (I think in my JSONSerialization, reported in Thread 1). Isn't the JSONDecoder just for dealing with however the server responds to my post request?

Comment: can you post raw json response of the request?

Comment: I believe that the server responds with a dictionary of [String : Int] for the [status : 200], I can try and get the actual JSON for that if needed, (still same error when anticipating [String : Int])

Comment: you need to update your model according to json.